# How to prevent a view from rotating in nativescript?

Tags: ios, view, uiview, nativescript

I need my camera view in nativescript to not rotate when the screen orientation has changed. But I need everything else to rotate. So in nativescript how would I prevent a single View or component from rotating? In iOS you can use viewcontroller methods to achieve a similar function but I don't see how I can prevent a specific view from not rotating. I am using angular in nativescript. Basically how the iOS camera app acts if you rotate the UI elements rotate but the actual camera view doesn't

How would I achieve this effect in nativescript?

Comment: When you say camera view, may I know which plugin you are using? Are you using nativescript-camera (which opens device camera) Or something like  nativescript-camera-plus that allows you to embed a camera view?

Comment: something like nativescript-camera-plus. But this applies to any view. I just need to stop the view from rotating.

Comment: As you mentioned in your question, you may use `UIViewController` (`Page`) to achieve this. You will have to force `shouldAutorotate` to attribute of your Page's UIViewController instance to return false. An example could be found [here](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-orientation/blob/master/src/orientation.js#L274-L295), the plugin in the example deals with topmost frame. You will have to point it to your particular frame and Page where you have placed the camera view.

Comment: @Manoj would this also stop all the rotation of other elements on the page? I need the camera view ONLY to stop rotating.

Comment: Again as I mentioned, place your Camera View within it's own Frame and Page. Since {N} v4 you have option place any number of Frame / Page at nested into each other.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, i tried using your method by replacing frame.Topmost with page :
    var curPage = this.page;
     var app = curFrame.viewController;

But when it still rotate the whole app instead of the current view/page, any idea why?